# Android hybrid_local App - Windows

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to use the Salesforce MobileSDK to build the hybrid_local test app for Android. I am following the guides step by step but the app always fails at building.

Has anyone ever succeeded in building it in Windows environment using forcedroid? I think it is impossible at the moment and I should use the library from git, can someone confirm this?

Thanks
T.

Comment: yes i have succeeded in running the hybrid app using forcedroid.can u post the error which you are facing?

Comment: Using forcedroid and following the procedure as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_mobile_services.meta/salesforce_platform_mobile_services/android_new_project.htm in eclipse there are a bunch of permission missing (GET_ACCOUTNS, MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, etc), adding them creates some sort of problem with USERS "ClientManager$AccountInfoNotFoundException: No user account found". If I try to execute the procedure without eclipse I can't see the error-log but the App doesn't work anyway. I am able to have the app to work if I take it from git though.